# The false claim that resemblance to real people is accidental

Tags: legal

Someone recently asked about the false claim that a movie was based on a true story. I often wonder about the opposite claim: Any resemblance to actual persons living or dead is entirely coincidental. It is strange that this message often appears after a film in which such a resemblance is obviously not entirely coincidental. Apparently this affords some kind of legal protection anyhow?